# Intent not finding Gmail App for email... Please see code - I've look at other answers... Xiaomi MI 8 API 27

Tags: android, email, android-intent

Setting up the intent is pretty straight forward...

I have tried using ACTION_SEND as well in place of ACTION_SENDTO for both areas.

```
 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context
            , context.getString(R.string.package_file_provider)
            , zipFile);


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.fromParts("mailto:", "noreply@gmail.com", null));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, zipFileName);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your file is attached.");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    //      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    if(isMailClientPresent(context)) {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send file via email..."));
    }
```

Specifically checking for email apps before calling the email intent

```
public static boolean isMailClientPresent(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if(list.size() == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

I have looked at many other answers on this and none seem to fix this issue... I've found the function above and it returns true... that would mean it finds the app... why the hades do I still get No apps can perform this action still?

Comment: your intent and the `isMailClientPresent` method are checking for different conditions.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thanks for pointing that out...I just changed it, same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void addAutoStartup() {

try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
    } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
    } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
    } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
    }

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if  (list.size() > 0) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exc" , String.valueOf(e));
}
```

}

Comment: Raju Tukadiya  Telling me to check app settings as a result

Comment: Very strange... I cannot seem to find gmail in this list it provided of apps...  I guess I will try to download some other email app to see if that is the problem. I'm lost

Comment: let me check give me some otherwise contact to my email :rajutukadiya3@gmail.com